# Getting Applet not initialized error

Tags: java, swing, applet, awt, frame

is everything is right in my programme??
 When i run it the a screen appears but it says that Applet is not initialized

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JobseekerLogin extends Frame {

public void CreateFrame(){
Frame frame = new Frame("Frame in Java Swing");
frame.setSize(400, 400);
frame.setVisible(true);
Label lb = new Label("Username");
add("East",lb);
add("West",new TextArea(""));
Label lb1 = new Label("Password");
add("East",lb1);
add("West",new TextArea(""));
}

public static void main(String []args){
  JobseekerLogin obj = new JobseekerLogin();
  obj.CreateFrame();
}
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This class is not launching as an applet as it does not extend `JApplet` or `Applet`.

Even when this is fixed, nothing will appear in the applet client. Applets do not call the `main` method but rather `init`. Also don't create a new `Frame` for applet components - add them to the applet container itself.

Rather than using the old heavyweight AWT, use lightweight `Swing`. Also look at [Java Web Start](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/) for deployment.

Comment: thank you very much, i am new to java. Can you direct me to any website or something where i can learn more about it??

Comment: Follow the trail: [Java Applets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/)

Answer (score 1):

This is Not an Applet. I think you need to check out the Life cycle of an Applet Here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/lifeCycle.html

Comment: if it's not applet then what is it??? or the right question would be how can i make it applet pgm??

Comment: @ChandrakantSingh If You have read the Link I have sent you and checked the Answer Below from Reimus An Applet requires init method in place of the main Method you have Also you have extended Frame Innstead of JApplet or Applet. To amke this an Applet you need to Follow the Applet Life cycle and Add init, start, stop or destroy Methods.